# is it possible to exclude a topic from a broker in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am new to kafka!!

Is it possible to exclude a topic from a broker in apache kafka?? How?

**To run a producer for a topic we give the command:**

> bin/kafka-console-producer.sh  --broker-list   localhost:9092  --topic kafkatopic

we do not have the option of broker in this command. Can we exclude broker anyways, either command line or java API??

Also is there any documentation of java API for Kafka? Any tutorials??

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Here is the 0.9 Java API: https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html

Comment: Why don't you ask what you're really try to accomplish, cuz' your question makes little or no sense :)

Comment: @Marko : I am novice in kafka. Just exploring its capabilities. just had this question in mind and posted!! ;)

Comment: Cool, welcome to Kafka community, no shame in being a novice, just wondering what does it mean to "exclude a topic" or to "exclude a broker".